# ubuntu16.04: Home link in Places is always opened by Phpstorm

Tags: 16.04, gtk, ubuntu-mate

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 with MATE 1.12.1. After openning Jetbrains Toolbox and installing PHPstorm, 'Home' directory link in 'Places' is always opened by PHPstorm. I tried to remove all jetbrains and storm config files/directories, removed installation and after reinstalling it again the problem returned. I'm sure I must have changed something i just cannot find what. If someone can help with that i would much appreciate it.

Comment: Please add output of `cat ~/.config/mimeapps.list` and `cat ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to the question (if it is long and big - use pastebin).

Comment: thanks for comment, i found problem in ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list, phpstorm was set as a handler for inode, i removed it and it works, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the contents of the following files:

- `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

and remove any occurrences of PHPstorm from them.